# How to assign result of a select into sqlplus variable

Tags: oracle, cmd, sqlplus

i am writing a batch file for wizard create my tablespace.
after few days my result for this wizard is code of bellow.

i create a variable named 'Path'.
then i select my datafile location and stored it into 'Path'.

because i could not use 'Path' in our create statement, then i defined a variable in sqlplus named 'Loc' and i passed value of 'path' into 'Loc'.

here is my script:

```
sqlplus >var path varchar2(100) 
sqlplus >exec select substr(name, 1, instr(name, 'USER') - 1) || 'test.ora' into :path from v$datafile where name like '%USER%'; 

sqlplus >def loc=:path

sqlplus >CREATE TABLESPACE test
1 > LOGGING 
2 >     BLOCKSIZE 16384  DATAFILE '&loc' SIZE 100M REUSE
3 > AUTOEXTEND
4 >     ON NEXT  50M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL 
5 > SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;
```

result of my script was:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE test
  2  LOGGING
  3  BLOCKSIZE 16384  DATAFILE '&loc' SIZE 100M REUSE
  4   AUTOEXTEND
  5   ON NEXT  50M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
  6   SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;
old   3: BLOCKSIZE 16384  DATAFILE '&loc' SIZE 100M REUSE
new   3: BLOCKSIZE 16384  DATAFILE ':path' SIZE 100M REUSE
CREATE TABLESPACE test
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file ':path'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 123) The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind variables won't help in DDL, static or otherwise. Stick with substitution variables:

```
column loc new_value loc

select substr(name, 1, instr(name, 'USER') - 1) || 'test.ora' as loc
from   v$datafile where name like '%USER%';

create tablespace test
logging
blocksize 16384
datafile '&loc' size 100m reuse
autoextend on next 50m maxsize unlimited
extent management local
segment space management auto;
```